# What are the cases when a React component's constructors are called?

Tags: reactjs

I've noticed that my component's constructors are called many times, including in times where I don't want it to. They have parent and child components that update their states often, and I noticed that when the parent updates its state, my child component's constructors are called again.

**Background info:**

The reason why this is an issue for me is because in my child component's constructors, I `fetch` data. And they're inside a for loop. So that's causing many `fetch`s to occur because my constructors are called many times.

**TLDR:**

What exactly are all the times a constructor is called for a component? It seems that they're called, even after they're already rendered.

Comment: Basically anytime that a prop that a child component uses changes, the child will be re-rendered: https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html

Comment: except React will not regenerate that child, it'll diff it first, and if that diff comes back as "this is a new element" it generates a new one. Otherwise, it merely updates it. So: What does your code look like @AskYous? Did you remember to add `key` attributes (and a real key, not "an array index", which tells you nothing about which actual child is involved) if those children are dynamically created, so that React can see it's "the same child, with updated props"?

Comment: From the docs: "The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted."  Sounds like you need to set up a condition for how/when you make your fetch.

Comment: Don't call `fetch` in the constructor of a class component. the correct place to fetch data is in `componentDidMount()`. Also it would be helpful to actually see some code. Your child components `constructor`s being called again indicates, that they get unmounted and mounted again.

Answer (score 2):

Basically every time the class gets instantiated. If you're seeing it called multiple times on one component then it is unmounting and re-mounting.